# Integral of real function is complex

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to compute the following (indefinite) integral:

$$\int e^x x^{2/3} dx $$

```
Integrate[E^x (x)^(2/3), x]
Plot[{Re[%], Im[%]}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

Output is:

[image]

That the integral is complex for $x<0$ makes sense to me, since the integrand is. But for $x>0$ the latter is real, why is the integral complex?

Comment: Your function isn't real for x<0!

Comment: `Integrate[E^x x^(2/3), {x, 0, x}]`

Comment: If differentiating the anti derivative gives back the integrand ($\pm$ constant in anti is OK), then the result is correct, which is in this case. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WPUs.png)

Comment: The integrand is not real.  It's multivalued (like $z^{1/3}$ is).  The discontinuity arises from integrating it using a multivalued antiderivative over  a path which is not analytically continuous, that is, across its branch point at the origin.  Look at `ComplexExpand[x^(2/3)/(-x)^(2/3)]` and note how the argument of x abruptly changes from $0$ to $\pi$ across the branch  point as $x$ changes from negative to positive giving rise to the discontinuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antiderivative is calculated with a complex integration constant. Its value is here

```
Limit[(x^(2/3)*Gamma[5/3, -x])/(-x)^(2/3), x -> 0, 
Direction -> "FromAbove"]   
(* (-(-1)^(1/3))*Gamma[5/3] *)
```

and you can subtract it like :

```
Integrate[E^x*x^(2/3), x]
Plot[{Re[% + (-1)^(1/3)*Gamma[5/3]], Im[% + (-1)^(1/3)*Gamma[5/3]], 
NIntegrate[E^y (y)^(2/3), {y, 0, x}]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Dashed}]
```

[image]
The corrected antiderivative (blue line) coincides with the numerical integration (dashed green) and the imaginary part (red) is gone.